# Adding mutability through extension

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants

I have a `Data` class and a `Wrapper` class which provides methods to access the `Data`. The `WrapperMutable` class extends `Wrapper` to add methods to modify the `Data`.

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Data {
public:
    void update();  // non-const method which modifies internal state of Data
};

class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper(shared_ptr<Data const> data) : myData(data) {}  // accepts const pointer
  // ...bunch of functions providing read-only access to aspects of the Data...
protected:
  shared_ptr<Data const> myData;  // stores const pointer
};

// Extend Wrapper with methods to modify the wrapped Data.
class WrapperMutable : public Wrapper
{
public:
  WrapperMutable(shared_ptr<Data> data) : Wrapper(data) {}

  // ERROR: invoking non-const method on const object:
  void updateData() { myData->update(); } 
};
```

The problem of course is with the `const`-ness of the wrapped `Data` object, which means that `WrapperMutable` can't modify it.

I considered changing `Wrapper` to accept and store non-`const` `Data`, but often the client itself will only have access to `const Data`, so they would then be forced to `const_cast` or copy in order to create a `Wrapper`.

So the only way I've been able to achieve this is by keeping an additional non-`const` pointer in the `WrapperMutable` class, and using this in mutable contexts:

```
class WrapperMutable : public Wrapper
{
public:
  WrapperMutable(shared_ptr<Data> data) : Wrapper(data), myMutableData(data) {}

  // Use myMutableData instead of the const myData
  void updateData() { myMutableData->update(); }

private:
  shared_ptr<Data> myMutableData;  // non-const pointer to the same Data as in Wrapper
};
```

Is there a better way? Clearly, deriving `WrapperMutable` from `Wrapper` is the source of my problem, but I don't want to have to reimplement all the methods of `Wrapper` in `WrapperMutable` either.

Comment: Can't you just change `shared_ptr<Data const> myData` to `const shared_ptr<Data> myData`? This would also allow the definition of `Wrapper(Data * const data) : myData(data) {}`

Comment: "but often the client itself will only have access to `const Data`" -- I think this is the root cause of the problem. If they can not modify `Data`, then also should not pass that `Data` to anyone who can modify it.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I think this would still force a client holding a pointer to `const Data` to perform a `const_cast`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @atkins I think I missed a point or two.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance expresses a "Kind of" relationship.

constness is not a "kind-of" relationship.

A const thing is a very different kind of thing to a mutable thing.

The model of shared_ptr itself shows how to express this relationship. A shared_ptr to mutable Data is convertible to shared_ptr of const Data but not the other way around.

You can express this relationship thus:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Data
{
};

struct const_data_wrapper
{
    const_data_wrapper(std::shared_ptr<const Data> p) : _impl(std::move(p)) {}

    void which() const {
        std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<const Data> _impl;
};

struct data_wrapper
{
    data_wrapper(std::shared_ptr<Data> p) : _impl(std::move(p)) {}

    const_data_wrapper as_const() const {
        return const_data_wrapper(_impl);
    }

    void which() const {
        std::cout << "not const" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Data> _impl;
};

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    auto w1 = data_wrapper(make_shared<Data>());
    auto w2 = w1.as_const();

    w1.which();
    w2.which();

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
not const
const
```

Answer (score 1):

If *bunch of functions providing read-only access to aspects of the Data* don't need to increment the `shared_ptr` and instead only need (`const`) access to the pointed data, then following oop approach would work:

```
class BaseWrapper {
public:
    // ...bunch of functions providing read-only access to aspects of the Data...
protected:
    virtual const Data* getData() = 0;
    virtual ~BaseWrapper(){}
};

class WrapperConst: public BaseWrapper {
public:
   WrapperConst(shared_ptr<Data const> data) : myData(data) {}
protected:
    const Data* getData() {
        return myData.get();
    };
private:
    shared_ptr<Data const> myData;
};

class WrapperMutable : public BaseWrapper {
public:
    WrapperMutable(shared_ptr<Data> data) : myData(data) {}
    void updateData() { myData->update(); }
protected:
   const Data* getData() {
        return myData.get();
    };
private:
    shared_ptr<Data> myData;
};
```

Advantage: You don't need another copy of the `shared_ptr`.

Disadvantages: You now use virtual functions that you didn't need otherwise. The read-only functions don't have access to the `shared_ptr`, so they may not make copies of it. More boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't need a `shared_ptr<>` in `WrapperMutable`, a raw pointer will do:

```
class WrapperMutable : public Wrapper
{
public:
  WrapperMutable(Data* data):
    Wrapper{shared_ptr<Data const>{data}},
    myMutableData{data} {}

  // Use myMutableData instead of the const myData
  void updateData() { myMutableData->update(); }

private:
  Data* myMutableData;  // non-const pointer to the same Data as in Wrapper
};
```

At least that saves you from incrementing and decrementing the reference counter.

From a software design point of view, are you sure, that `WrapperMutable` "is a" `Wrapper`? My gutt feeling says, that you are breaking the single responsibility principle somewhere. That is among the most reasons for design issues I have seen.

BTW.: Please reconsider, if a `shared_ptr<>` really is what you need here. It is often overused as a replacement for garbage collection. Use it, when you really want to state shared ownership. Prefer raw pointers for no ownership and `unique_ptr<>` for unique ownership. The reason is, that `shared_ptr<>` in contrast to raw pointers and `unique_ptr<>` is not free of cost. It reuquires an additional increment and decrement of the reference counter and usually an additional level of indirection when you dereference it. `unique_ptr<>` on the other hand will create the same code as a raw pointer with correctly places deletes all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Data {
public:
    void update() {}  // non-const method which modifies internal state of Data
};


//Basic wrapper
template <typename D>
class BaseWrapper {
    public:     
        BaseWrapper(shared_ptr<D> data) : myData(data) {}

    protected:
        shared_ptr<D> myData;
};

template <typename D, bool const = std::is_const<D>::value>
class Wrapper : public BaseWrapper<D>
{
};

//Const-Version
template <typename D>
class Wrapper<D, true> : public BaseWrapper<D>
{
public:
    Wrapper(shared_ptr<D> data) : BaseWrapper(data) {}
};

//Non-Const-Version
template <typename D>
class Wrapper<D, false> : public BaseWrapper<D>
{
public:
    Wrapper(shared_ptr<D> data) : BaseWrapper(data) {}
    void updateData() { myData->update(); }
};



int main()
{
    Wrapper<Data> a(nullptr);
    Wrapper<const Data> b(nullptr);
    a.updateData();
    b.updateData();//error C2039: 'updateData': is not a member of 'Wrapper<const Data,true>'
}
```